# Параноя чи паранойя?

Tags: вживання-слів, терміни, іменники, запозичені-слова, орфографія

У [CУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/paranojja) знаходжу такий варіант:

> **ПАРАНО́ЙЯ**, ї, жін. Рідка форма психічного захворювання, що характеризується стійкими маячними ідеями при збереженні формальної логічності мислення.

Однак вже в [Орфографічному словнику](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F) це слово пишуть без літери ***й***:

> **параноя** - іменник, жіночий рід, неістота, однина і множина.

Останній варіант зафіксований і в безлічі Інтернет-статей, зокрема [тут](https://newmedicina.in.ua/paranoya-etiologiya-priznaki-prichini-likuvannya/), [тут](http://a-yak.com/paranoya-yavnoyu-simptomatiki-ne-sposterigayetsya/) та ін.

То як же правильно: ***параноя*** чи ***паранойя***?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можна ж побачити на тому самому СУМ-11, котрого навели, внизу напис червоним кольором:

> Увага! Подане тут оригінальне написання реєстрового слова є застарілим.

Достемено відомо, ну, хоча би повинно здавати ся так через приросток [*пара~*](//etymonline.com/word/para-), що слово чужомовного походження. Дивимо в [правопис 2015 року](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p4) відповідного роздїлу:

> 4. **I**, **y** (а також **u** німецького дифтонга **eu**) в позиції між двома голосними (в іноземній мові) в загальних назвах звичайно не передаються окремим знаком: *буєр*, *конвеєр*, *лояльний*, ***параноя***, *плеяда*, *рояль*, *саквояж*, *секвоя*, *фаянс*, *феєрверк*; але: *Гойя*, *Савойя*, *Фейєрбах*; також *майя* (народність), *фойє*.

Окрім правила, навіть приклад має ся: **параноя**. А новіший [правопис 2019 року](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=157) навіть відкинув непотрібні винятки:

> Звук **[j]** звичайно передаємо відповідно до вимови іншомовного слова буквою **й**,
> а у звукосполученнях **[je]**, **[ji]**, **[ju]**, **[ja]** буквами **є**, **ї**, **ю**, **я**: *бо́єр*, *є́ті*, *інʼє́кція*, *конве́єр*, *пле́єр*, *проє́кт*, *проє́кція*, *субʼє́кт*, *траєкто́рія*, *феєрве́рк*, *фла́єр*, *фоє́;* *круї́з*, *моза́їка*; *лоя́льний*, ***парано́я***, *плея́да*, *роя́ль*, *саквоя́ж*, *секво́я*, *фая́нс*; *Йога́нн*; *Єйтс*, *Кає́нна*, *Ма́єр*, *Рамбує́*, *Со́єр*, *Феєрба́х*, *Хеєрда́л*; *Гаї́ті*; *Юно́на*; *Го́я*, *Іса́я*, *Саво́я*, *Хая́м*.

---

Взагалї, вставлення **й** перед йотованими — московський звичай правопису, оскільки **е** може читати ся як **е** (*карате* при **э**), **йо** (*ее* при **ё**) та **є**, і аби вказати саме останього способу, додавали **й**, що також полегшувало відмінювання, тому це розповсюджило ся і на инші йотовані. А пізніше і на українську, котра цього не потребувала, під час совітського поневолення. Ось старіший [правопис 1928 року](//r2u.org.ua/node/245) наводе дуже помітні приклади:

> Дифтонг **eu** передаємо через **ев**: *неврастенія*, *неврологія*, *невтральний*, *невтралітет* і т. ін., але нім. **eu** через **ой**: *Нойман* (Neumann), *Ойтінґ* (Euting) і т. iн., також *Фоєрбах* (Feuerbach).

Тобто з *Фоєрбах* отримали *Фейєрбах*. Значну частину таки скасували, але декотрі, як і оце слово, залишило ся в винятках. Хоча [проєкт 1999 року](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1999_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) подавав всюди таке скасувати:

> Не писати зайвої букви **й** у словах, де його немає в мові-джерелі запозичення: *гуаява*, *мая*, *фоє*.
>
> У мовах-джерелах у цих словах подвійний **й** не вимовляють і не пишуть: іспанські *guayaba*, *maya*, французьке *foyer*.

Answer (score 2):

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах виданий у 1970-х роках, тому правопис деяких слів може відрізнятися від сучасного.

Його наступних, «Словник української мови» в 20 томах 2010-х років, хоча й не має ще томів зі словами на літеру «П», однак у статті [важковиліко́вний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=196663&page=233) містить цитату:

> Шизофренія, епілепсія, **параноя**, прогресивний параліч, маніакально-депресивний психоз — усі ці психічні хвороби є важковиліковними або взагалі невиліковними (з наук.-попул. літ.).

Отже я підтримую [відповідь follower](/a/4430), що правильно *параноя*.

<sub>Також додам, що [проект правопису 2018 року](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_2018_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), мені здається, збирається майже зовсім прибрати з українських слів подвійні йотування (буквосполуки *-йя-*, *-йє-*, *-йї-*, *-йю-*) — окрім слова *[війя́](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14536&page=469)* (у значенні «дишель у воловій упряжі»; не плутати зі словом *[ві́я](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14503&page=468)* в значенні «волосинка на краю повіки»). Принаймні він каже, що «букви *я*, *ю*, *є* пишемо: 1. На  початку  слова,  після  голосного  та  після  апострофа  для позначення звукосполучень *й* + *а*, *й* + *у*, *й* + *е*: *я́кість*, *юроди́вий*, *єство́*; *моя́*, *зна́ю*, *твоє́*; *п’ять*, *м’я́та*, *в’юн*, *б’ють*, *п’ємо́*, а також після *й* у слові *війя́* (*війю́*, *на війї́*). 2. Після приголосного для позначення його м’якості: *дя́дько*, *лю́ди*, *оста́ннє*, *сюди́*, *ряд*, *ря́сно*, *рюкза́к*, *рюш*» — і жодних інших випадків не зазначає. Однак проект 2018 року ще не ухвалено (й можливо, не буде ухвалено зовсім), тому поки що на нього надто зважати не варто.</sub>